# Calculate the actual duration of a pandas rolling offset window

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has a `rolling()` function to perform calculations on windows of Series and DataFrame objects. If the index is datetime (or you reference the datetime column using the `on` argument), `rolling()` can be performed over an offset, like 2 seconds or 7 days.

I would like to calculate the actual duration of each window, not the offset. The best I can think of is to duplicate the timestamp column, set one to the index, then use `rolling()` to get the min and max. However, the fresh Timestamp column is dropped after calling `rolling()`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                  'Tm': [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:10'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:12'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:16'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:19'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:20')]})

df['t'] = df['Tm']
print(df)
max_times = df.rolling('5s', on='Tm').max()
min_times = df.rolling('5s', on='Tm').min()
print(max_times)
print((max_times - min_times).astype('timedelta64[s]'))
```

Output:

```
   B                  Tm                   t
0  0 2013-01-01 09:00:00 2013-01-01 09:00:00
1  1 2013-01-01 09:00:02 2013-01-01 09:00:02
2  2 2013-01-01 09:00:03 2013-01-01 09:00:03
3  3 2013-01-01 09:00:05 2013-01-01 09:00:05
4  4 2013-01-01 09:00:06 2013-01-01 09:00:06
5  5 2013-01-01 09:00:10 2013-01-01 09:00:10
6  6 2013-01-01 09:00:12 2013-01-01 09:00:12
7  7 2013-01-01 09:00:16 2013-01-01 09:00:16
8  8 2013-01-01 09:00:19 2013-01-01 09:00:19
9  9 2013-01-01 09:00:20 2013-01-01 09:00:20
     B                  Tm
0  0.0 2013-01-01 09:00:00
1  1.0 2013-01-01 09:00:02
2  2.0 2013-01-01 09:00:03
3  3.0 2013-01-01 09:00:05
4  4.0 2013-01-01 09:00:06
5  5.0 2013-01-01 09:00:10
6  6.0 2013-01-01 09:00:12
7  7.0 2013-01-01 09:00:16
8  8.0 2013-01-01 09:00:19
9  9.0 2013-01-01 09:00:20
         B   Tm
0 00:00:00  0.0
1 00:00:01  0.0
2 00:00:02  0.0
3 00:00:02  0.0
4 00:00:03  0.0
5 00:00:01  0.0
6 00:00:01  0.0
7 00:00:01  0.0
8 00:00:01  0.0
9 00:00:02  0.0
```

Surely there's a more elegant (and functional) technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by:

- setting the timestamp column as the index,
- defining a function that takes a DataFrame (in this case, fragments from the `rolling()` function), converts the index to an integer, and returns the difference between the minimum and maximum values of the index array,
- call `rolling()` on the DataFrame and use the `apply()` function which lets you specify a function to use.

Documentation for the `apply()` function is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'Tm': [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:10'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:12'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:16'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:19'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:20')]})

def duration(X):
    ind = pd.to_numeric(X.index) * 10**-9 # Convert from nanoseconds to seconds. 
    return ind.max() - ind.min()

df = df.set_index("Tm")
print(df)
durations = df.rolling("5s").apply(duration) 
df.reset_index()
print(durations)
```

Output:

```
                     B
Tm                    
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  0
2013-01-01 09:00:10  0
2013-01-01 09:00:12  0
2013-01-01 09:00:16  0
2013-01-01 09:00:19  0
2013-01-01 09:00:20  0
                       B
Tm                      
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
2013-01-01 09:00:10  4.0
2013-01-01 09:00:12  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:16  4.0
2013-01-01 09:00:19  3.0
2013-01-01 09:00:20  4.0
```

Comment: While your solution works perfectly well for the given example, keep in mind that `apply()` becomes very slow for larger dataframes because the operation is not vectorized. Instead, just could just add the datetimes as integer to the dataframe and calulcate the duration by substracting `df.rolling('5s').max()` and `df.rolling('5s').min()`.